# Filter a tableview with UISearchResultsUpdating

Tags: swift, uitableview, uisearchbar

I have a very large array of data that I use a searchbar to filter. However I would like to filter only exactly that which the user enters in the searchbar. I.e. if you type "b" you only get items starting with b. The list is more than 200,000 items so now even with many letters entered the results showing are often irrelevant. I have tried searching a lot but every guide I have found is a variation of what I have :

```
extension MapTableController : UISearchResultsUpdating {
    func filterContentForSearchText(_ searchText: String) {
            if(searchText == "") {
                matchingItems = []
            }

            else {
                matchingItems = arrayOfFixes.filter { fix in
                    return fix.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased())
                }
                tableView.reloadData()
            }
    }

    func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
        let searchText = searchController.searchBar.text
        filterContentForSearchText(searchText!)
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

I understand that using "contains" will have the above mentioned effect. But I can't figure out how to filter it in the desired way. For example I would like it so that if I enter "Ben" it will show results like "Bendi", "Benhu", "Benji" etc. Not so that it shows results like "Juben", "Ibeno" etc, you get the picture.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use 'hasPrefix' instead of 'contains' for your filter:

```
return fix.lowercased().hasPrefix(searchText.lowercased())
```